# Request params not getting bound to grails command object

Tags: grails, grails-controller, grails-2.1

I've upgraded to use Grails 2.1.1 from Grails 1.3.6 and some command objects which were working are no longer getting data binding from the request parameters.

I created an experimental controller to reproduce the problem:

```
package my.controllers

import troubleshooting.*

class ExperimentalController {


    def toggle(ExperimentalCommand cmd){
        render "<pre>${this.properties}</pre>"
        render "<h3>Raw</h3>The cmd.id was/is '${cmd.id}'<br/>The params.id was/is '${params.id}'<br/>They should be the same but they aren't<br/>The target ala cmd then params was/is '${cmd.target}' '${params.target}'<br/><hr/><hr/>"
        bindData(cmd,params)//not even this works wtf?
        render "<h3>bindData(cmd,params)</h3>The cmd.id was/is '${cmd.id}'<br/>The params.id was/is '${params.id}'<br/>They should be the same but they aren't<br/>The target ala cmd then params was/is '${cmd.target}' '${params.target}'<br/><hr/><hr/>"
        cmd = new ExperimentalCommand()
        render "<h3>New Cmd</h3>The cmd.id was/is '${cmd.id}'<br/>The params.id was/is '${params.id}'<br/>They should be the same but they aren't<br/>The target ala cmd then params was/is '${cmd.target}' '${params.target}'<br/><hr/><hr/>"
        cmd = new ExperimentalCommand(params)
        render "<h3>New Cmd binding constructor</h3>The cmd.id was/is '${cmd.id}'<br/>The params.id was/is '${params.id}'<br/>They should be the same but they aren't<br/>The target ala cmd then params was/is '${cmd.target}' '${params.target}'<br/><hr/><hr/>"
        bindData(cmd,params,[include:["id","target"]])
        render "The cmd.id was/is '${cmd.id}'<br/>The params.id was/is '${params.id}'<br/>They should be the same but they aren't<br/>The target ala cmd then params was/is '${cmd.target}' '${params.target}'<br/><hr/><hr/>"

    }
}
class ExperimentalCommand{
    def id,target,action,controller

}
```

If you execute:

grails run-app

With that and then go to:

```
http://localhost:8080/YourApp/experimental/toggle/foo?target=bullseye&cmd.target=whatever
```

You'll see (under my circumstances) that the first attempt to render the cmd.id shows it as null despite the fact that the params.id is foo

From this excercise I've also discovered that the bindData calls that don't specify include id and target exclusively fail AND instantiating the command object explicitly with the params causes an exception.

I'm at a complete loss here. I've tried things like overriding the getInstanceControllersApi method to return a wrapper that logs the different bindData calls so I can see what happens and how I might controll it only that told me nothing.

I can add controller and action fields to the command object to prevent it from erroring out when I call new ExperimentalCommand(params) but I shouldn't have to do any of that the Grails documentation states that the binding will get done on the instance of the command object before the action is called however in my case it is not.

Google hasn't turned up anything so apparently I am one of the first to have to deal with this.

The question is HOW can I trouble shoot this?

Answer (score 1):

There have been various changes to the data binding mechanism between 1.3.6 and 2.x, the first thing I would try is to give the command object properties proper types rather than just `def`

```
class ExperimentalCommand{
    String id
    String target
    String action
    String controller
}
```

[The Grails 2.1.1 docs](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.1/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding) for data binding talk about the `new CommandObject(params)` and `obj.properties = params` forms of data binding and state that

> These forms of data binding in Grails are very convenient, but also indiscriminate. In other words, they will bind all non-transient, **typed** *[my bold]* instance properties of the target object, including ones that you may not want bound.

Comment: I've tried those things too.
Per the docs Strictly typed is required so it can do the conversion but even that still comes up with null values in the command object

Comment: I just tweaked the logging settings to log the grails internals and spring classes at debug level and I've found:
`code`<pre>DEBUG validation.DataBinder  - Field [target] has been removed from PropertyValues and will not be bound, because it has not been found in the list of allowed fields
2012-11-20 12:43:32,469 [http-bio-443-exec-3] DEBUG validation.DataBinder  - Field [id] has been removed from PropertyValues and will not be bound, because it has not been found in the list of allowed fields
2012-11-20 12:43:32,469 [http-bio-443-exec-3]</pre>`code`

Comment: Have you changed to String? The id will not be binded because of security concerns, you will have to manually bind this, but all others I think that are allowed.

Comment: I just got it to work by adding:
    bindable: true 
to the constraints
I still think something is up though - that makes code a lot less dry and groovy; I'm now searching for a setting in my Config.groovy or BuildConfig.groovy that may have directed it to use this behavior